# How to implement a FIFO queue in a multi-threaded environment

Tags: java, multithreading, queue, synchronized

I am trying to implement a queue for a class that fetches `OpenGraph` data for a url.  The idea is that the `OpenGraphIO` service only allows for one request at a time if the request requires their "proxy" service. To eliminate the "simultaneous proxy request" errors from the service, I would like to implement a request queue inside a service class called `OpenGraphFetcherImpl`.  However, I can't figure out how to implement the actual queue itself inside the `fetch()` method.  Obviously the `fetch()` method can be called in a multi-threaded environment.

My class shell is below:

```
public class OpenGraphFetcherImpl implements OpenGraphFetcher {

    private static final String[] domainsThatRequireProxy = {"instagram.com","facebook.com"};

    private static final LinkedList<URL> proxyQueue = new LinkedList<>();

    private final String api_key;

    public OpenGraphFetcherImpl(String api_key) {
        this.api_key = api_key;
    }

    /**
     * Fetch OpenGraph information for a url.  If the url is invalid or no data is returned, the OpenGraph
     * object will be "empty" (non-null)
     * 
     * Only one "proxy" request can be made at a time. Should a proxy be needed, the request will be queued
     * and returned once previous requests have been completed.
     *
     * @param url end point to fetch OpenGraph data
     * @return OpenGraph object
     */
    @Override
    @Nonnull
    public OpenGraph fetch(URL url) {
        if (useProxy(url)) {
            // Clearly this code doesn't work, but logic should be to add the request to the queue and then make requests in FIFO order
            proxyQueue.add(url);
            return OpenGraphIO.fetchOpenGraphInfo(api_key, proxyQueue.poll(), true);
        } else {
            return OpenGraphIO.fetchOpenGraphInfo(api_key, url, false);
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param url url to test
     * @return true if the host of the url matches any domains that require use of a proxy
     */
    private boolean useProxy(URL url) {
        return Arrays.stream(domainsThatRequireProxy).parallel().anyMatch(url.getHost()::contains);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is OpenGraphFetcherImpl a singleton? If so, simply make the fetch method synchronized. If it is not a singleton, declare a static Object, and use that to synchronized on entrance to fetch so only one thread can invoke it at any given time.

Comment: It is a singleton.  That said, I could make fetch() synchronized, but I would also like fetch() not to be synchronized if useProxy(url) is false because the service allows simultaneous requests for non-proxy calls.  Would it make sense to create another method called "private synchronized fetchProxy()" that is called after the "if(useProxy(url))" part of the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your description, you'd want to limit synchronous calls to fetch() when `useProxy` is true. Then, you can use an object to synchronize that case only:

```
public class OpenGraphFetcherImpl implements OpenGraphFetcher {
    private static final Object fetchLock=new Object();

     public OpenGraph fetch(URL url) {
        if (useProxy(url)) {
            synchronized(fetchLock) {
               return OpenGraphIO.fetchOpenGraphInfo(api_key, url, true);
            }
        } else {
            return OpenGraphIO.fetchOpenGraphInfo(api_key, url, false);
        }
    }
...
```